# Create a better GA4 landing page report with BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Create a better GA4 landing page report with BigQuery

Hi everyone,
is there a way to recreate the standard Landing Page report of GA4 with Google BigQuery?

To be more specific this is an example of a standard GA4 Landing page Report, it show all landing pages related to an event called 'banner_click':

GA4 Landing Report

[image: 1]

The only problem is that in the column 'Landing Page' it shows /lading-page-1, /landing-page-2 etc. as partial path and I would like instead to read the full webiste url (example: https://website.com/landing-page-1)

So, how can I obtain the same view but with full url through BigQuery?

Thank you.

Searched for query examples related to landing pages, I've found this one:

`SELECT (SELECT value.string_value FROM unnest(event_params) WHERE key = "page_location") as page_location, count(*) as sessions, count(distinct user_pseudo_id) as users FROM` big-query-323234.analytics_343345454.events_20230306`WHERE  (SELECT value.int_value FROM unnest(event_params) WHERE key="entrances")=1 GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 2 DESC`

How can I modify this query to shows number of events for 'banner_click' event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do a count of `(select value.string_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'banner_click') as banner_click,` for your banner query

I would use this for the URL
`regexp_replace((select value.string_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'page_location'), r'\?.*', '') as page_location`, but am confused because your code should be spitting out a long url with all the utm codes on and not a short one missing out the http

Comment: Thank you for you answer.
Could you do a practical example?

Comment: This should work SELECT (regexp_replace((select value.string_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'page_location'), r'\?.*', '') as page_location, 
(select value.string_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'banner_click') as banner_click,
count(*) as sessions, count(distinct user_pseudo_id) as users FROM big-query-323234.analytics_343345454.events_20230306WHERE  (SELECT value.int_value FROM unnest(event_params) WHERE key="entrances")=1 GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 2 DESC